# Pseudo Class Support in ADF

Tags: css, jsf, oracle-adf

In my skin file (which is extending Skyros), I've defined a rule as

```
.arrow_box:after {
    /*some css rules */
}
.arrow_box:before {
    /*some css rules */
}
```

The main aim is to create an arrow on the top of the box just like the one shown at [CSSArrowPlease](http://cssarrowplease.com/).

## The Issue

When I run the page, the pseudo classes aren't being applied because they are getting changed into:

```
.arrow_box.p_AFAfter, .x1z2.p_AFAfter {
    /*some css rules */
}
.arrow_box.p_AFBefore, .x1z2.p_AFBefore {
    /*some css rules */
}
```

Notice how the `:` is converted into `.p_AFAfter` and `.p_AFBefore`. How would I avoid this?

I also tried escaping the selector:

```
.arrow_box\:after {
  /*some css rules */
}
```

But that got translated into

```
.arrow_box\.p_AFAfter, .x1z2.p_AFAfter {
    /*some css rules */
}
```

Any workaround to this? My jDeveloper version is **11.1.1.9.0**

## PS

`DISABLE_CONTENT_COMPRESSION` is not an option since I don't have control over the `web.xml` file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand that skin file is not really css file. It is skin file that processed by skinning engine. And you have to use it, when addressing components styles.
However if all that you need is just custom css, you can create simple css file and include it in your page. You can still keep it in skin project or create it in your web project.

This file won't be modified by skin engine and you will get all your styles as it is. But you won't be able to refer component styles and have to explictly provide css class names for components in `styleClass` property.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the CSS compression by adding this to your `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
  <description>Set to true to disable compression of CSS class names for
               skinning keys and have more human readable class
               names</description>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.DISABLE_CONTENT_COMPRESSION</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This will prevent your CSS classes to be obfuscated.

Comment: Well, this will certainly help at the localhost level. But once I deploy my application to webcenter portal, it will fail again since on the server, the `DISABLE_CONTENT_COMPRESSION` key will be set to `false`